# Cannot connect any more to IBM personal communication ver.13 with VBA

Tags: vba

I have a question (hopefully I explain it correct on the right forum).

Previously this VBA macro was working perfectly. I had Excel 2013 and Windows 8.
Now it not working any more on Office 365 (desktop version) and Windows 10.

This code is designed to connect to IBM personal communication ver.13 and extract information from a screen (like copy from IBM to Excel).

Below I have the code.
It keeps crashing at `Set pcommConnMgr = New AutConnMgr` (row 13 from the top)

```vb
Function PULSps() As AutPS
    'Make sure that these references are marked
    'PCOMM autECLConnMgr Automation Object 1.0 Library
    'PCOMM autECLOIA Automation Object 1.0 Library
    'PCOMM autECLPS Automation Object 1.0 Library
    'PCOMM autECLWinMetrics Automation Object 1.0 Library
    'Referenses are found under the TOOLS menu (look above in this window)
    
    Dim pcommConnMgr As AutConnMgr
    Dim intSessCount As Integer
    Dim intLoop As Integer
    Dim lngSessionHandle As Long
    Dim booProcessed As Boolean
    
    Set pcommConnMgr = New AutConnMgr
    'find the IBM PCC session
    intSessCount = pcommConnMgr.autECLConnList.Count
    If intSessCount = 0 Then
    ' if session not found then terminate program
        MsgBox "PULS was not found - program will terminate", , "No connection to PULS?"
        Application.Quit
    End If
    For intLoop = 1 To intSessCount
        Set PULSps = New AutPS
        With pcommConnMgr.autECLConnList(intLoop)
            lngSessionHandle = .Handle
            PULSps.SetConnectionByHandle lngSessionHandle
            ' check if session found is PULS
            ' I have choosen to do this by checking for VCP or VCCS. Those words is always
            ' in the same place on every PULS screen. Other system may have other words or
            ' you may choose not to check, if no check booProcessed should always be true
            If PULSps.GetText(23, 59, 4) = "VCP " Or PULSps.GetText(23, 59, 4) = "VCCS" Then
                intLoop = intSessCount
                booProcessed = True
            End If
        End With
    Next
    If booProcessed = False Then
        MsgBox "PULS was not found - program will terminate", , "No connection to PULS?"
        Application.Quit
    End If
End Function
    
Function PULSoia() As AutOIA
    'Make sure that these references are marked
    'PCOMM autECLConnMgr Automation Object 1.0 Library
    'PCOMM autECLOIA Automation Object 1.0 Library
    'PCOMM autECLPS Automation Object 1.0 Library
    'PCOMM autECLWinMetrics Automation Object 1.0 Library
    'Referenses are found under the TOOLS menu (look above in this window)
    
    Dim pcommConnMgr As AutConnMgr   'Personal Comm - Connection Manger
    Dim pcommWin As AutWinMetrics    'Personal Comm - Window Characteristics
    Dim pcommOIA As AutOIA           'Personal Comm - Operator Info Area
    Dim intSessCount As Integer     'Number of open sessions
    Dim intLoop As Integer
    Dim lngSessionHandle As Long    'Handle to 5250 Window
    Dim booProcessed As Boolean     'Flag marking successful process
    
    Set pcommConnMgr = New AutConnMgr
    intSessCount = pcommConnMgr.autECLConnList.Count
    If intSessCount = 0 Then
        MsgBox "PULS was not found - program will terminate", , "No connection to PULS?"
        Application.Quit
    End If
    
    For intLoop = 1 To intSessCount
        Set pcommWin = New AutWinMetrics
        Set PULSoia = New AutOIA
    
        With pcommConnMgr.autECLConnList(intLoop)
            lngSessionHandle = .Handle
            pcommWin.SetConnectionByHandle lngSessionHandle
            PULSoia.SetConnectionByHandle lngSessionHandle
    
        End With
        Set pcommWin = Nothing
    Next
End Function
    
Sub KollaPULS()
    '******* Variables *****************
    Dim pcommPS As AutPS
    Dim pcommOIA As AutOIA
    Dim RadNr As Integer
    Dim lngPartNr As Long
    Dim intNul As Integer
    Dim intNegen As Integer
    Dim StrPf8 As String
    Dim IntLoc As Integer
    Dim IntCount As Integer
    Dim strAprofDate As String
    
    '******** setting up functions to get info from PULS (ei IBM PCC) **********
    Set pcommOIA = PULSoia
    Set pcommPS = PULSps
    '****************** Clear out old data and put back headings ************************
    Sheets("Reports").Select
    Columns("A:F").Select
    Selection.ClearContents
    Range("A1").Value = "Partnumber"
    Range("B1").Value = "District": Range("C1").Value = "Reports"
    Range("D1").Value = "Qty hnd": Range("E1").Value = "Code"
    Range("F1").Value = "Date"
    Sheets("Partnumbers").Select
    
    '****************** work in PULS screen 3177 **********************************************
    IntLoc = 1
    RadNr = 2 '  start at row 2 (should be the first partnumber
    pcommPS.SendKeys "[HOME]"
    pcommPS.SendKeys "3177" ' print the screen number to position 1,2
    pcommPS.SendKeys "[enter]" ' then press enter to actually change to the screen
    pcommOIA.WaitForAppAvailable ' wait for PULS to update
    pcommOIA.WaitForInputReady
    
    'strAprofDate = Range("B2").Value
    
    lngPartNr = Val(Range("A" & Trim(Str(RadNr))).Value) ' get the partnumber in column A row RadNr
    intNul = 0
    intNegen = 9
    While lngPartNr > 0 'As long there is a partnumber in column A keep on working
        pcommPS.SendKeys "[home]"
        pcommPS.SendKeys "[newline]"
        pcommPS.SendKeys lngPartNr 'print partnumber to position 2,12 (where a partnumber i supposed to be entered)
        pcommPS.SendKeys "[tab]"
        pcommPS.SendKeys intNul
        pcommPS.SendKeys "[tab]"
        pcommPS.SendKeys intNul
        pcommPS.SendKeys "[tab]"
        pcommPS.SendKeys intNul
        pcommPS.SendKeys "[tab]"
        pcommPS.SendKeys intNegen
        pcommPS.SendKeys "[enter]" ' press enter to update screen with new partnumber
        pcommOIA.WaitForAppAvailable ' wait for PULS to update
        pcommOIA.WaitForInputReady
        StrPf8 = ""
        Do
            StrPf8 = Trim(pcommPS.GetText(23, 2, 15))
            For IntCount = 7 To 19
                'If Trim(pcommPS.GetText(IntCount, 39, 6)) = strAprofDate Then
                    'If Val(Trim(pcommPS.GetText(IntCount, 39, 6))) = 0 Then
                        IntLoc = IntLoc + 1
                        Sheets("Reports").Select
                        Range("A" & Trim(Str(IntLoc))).Value = lngPartNr
                        Range("B" & Trim(Str(IntLoc))).Value = Val(Trim(pcommPS.GetText(IntCount, 3, 5)))
                        Range("C" & Trim(Str(IntLoc))).Value = Val(Trim(pcommPS.GetText(IntCount, 16, 8)))
                        Range("D" & Trim(Str(IntLoc))).Value = Val(Trim(pcommPS.GetText(IntCount, 61, 4)))
                        Range("E" & Trim(Str(IntLoc))).Value = Val(Trim(pcommPS.GetText(IntCount, 65, 7)))
                        Range("F" & Trim(Str(IntLoc))).Value = Val(Trim(pcommPS.GetText(IntCount, 39, 7)))
                        Sheets("Partnumbers").Select
                    'End If
                'End If
            Next
            If StrPf8 = "402 MORE LINES" Then
                pcommPS.SendKeys "[pf8]"
            Else
                StrPf8 = ""
            End If
        Loop Until StrPf8 = ""
        
        RadNr = RadNr + 1
        lngPartNr = Val(Range("A" & Trim(Str(RadNr))).Value)
    Wend
    Sheets("Reports").Select
    Range("A2").Select
    MsgBox "Update Completed", , "Example to get info from IBM PCC"
End Sub
```

Can any one help me?

Comment: `keeps crashing` is not a helpful description. What error do you get?

Comment: Possible the library / dll to create an `AutConnMgr` object doesn't exist, or maybe it's just not referencing the right version in your new environment. Did you do as the macro suggested and `Make sure that these references are marked` in TOOLS > REFERENCES